# What is a "normal curvature matrix" of a specific surface? and how to calculate it?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

It is the first time that I meet the concept "normal curvature matrix".

By google searching, it seems like a concept in differential geometry. But I know little of differential geometry and do not get any clear definition, properties of it or information on how to calculate it.

Is there any references or ideas on how to understand it?

1)Google books:
[Google books link](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=6YCC9U9_1UkC&pg=PA341&lpg=PA341&dq=%22normal%20curvature%20matrix%22&source=bl&ots=0BLTU20-qt&sig=KC4elM4wTzncU0UWMXLvjOSouPQ&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=0E_yUt_DLoaDiQealYD4Dg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22normal%20curvature%20matrix%22&f=false)

2)Springer book:
[Springer book link](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm:978-3-642-29846-2/1.pdf)

The content in the second link made me believe this should be a concept in differential geometry.

Comment: Most likely it **is** differential geometry, but for better understanding it would be better to describe the context.

Comment: As a differential geometer, I have not come across this term, and neither has Google. What is the source where you found the term used? I am guessing that it refers to the curvature of the canonical connection on the normal bundle of a submanifold of a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: @BenMcKay you should use `"normal curvature matrix"` with the quotation marks for google search; I have updated it with the two links I found.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev the concept would be that in the first link. It is used to determine whether a numerical solution $x^*$ is local minimum or not. Since there is already positive definite  `Hessian` which also requires second order derivative information, what is the advantage of using the maximum eigen value of this `normal curvature matrix`?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the Weingarten map, or shape operator.  This can be seen as a map from the tangent space of the surface to itself.  It takes a tangent vector $v$ to the derivative of the normal in the direction $v$.

Comment: I want to understand how this concept can be used for the local minimum criterion in unconstrained nonlinear optimization, the proof and its advantage over `Hessian` (positive semi-definiteness). Any suggestions? thank you!